# Bounding rectangle collision resolution

Tags: c#, xna, collision-detection

I'm working on an XNA game framework, of sorts. My current project in this is about collision detection/resolution. I've got a semi-working method of collision detection. However, my problem is in directional collision. I want to be able to see if another object is colliding on this objects, for example, right side.

My problem is, however, that, no matter how I resolve collision, I get stuck inside of another object below me, which then, consequently, counts as being collided on the right as well.

I know this is a bit of a vague question, but I've been trying to figure this out for a few days now, and haven't hit upon a solution.

Any ideas?

```
public ICollidable IsCollidedOnLeftAny()
{
    return (from ICollidable collidable in ParentObject.ParentState.ObjectList where collidable.GetCollidableComponent() != this where IsCollidedOnRight(collidable) select collidable).FirstOrDefault();
}

    public bool IsCollidedWithObject(ICollidable collidable, CollisionMode mode)
    {
        if (IsGhost || collidable.GetCollidableComponent().IsGhost) return false;

        switch (mode)
        {
            case CollisionMode.BoundingCircle:
                var distanceVector = collidable.GetTransformComponent().Position - ParentObject.Transform.Position;

                return distanceVector.Length() <= BoundingCircleRadius + collidable.GetCollidableComponent().BoundingCircleRadius;

            case CollisionMode.BoundingRectangle:
                return BoundingRectangle.Intersects(collidable.GetCollidableComponent().BoundingRectangle);
        }

        return false;
    }

    public bool IsCollidedOnLeft(ICollidable collidable) // Is this object collided on ITS OWN LEFT SIDE with the given object?
    {
        return BoundingRectangle.Right > collidable.GetCollidableComponent().BoundingRectangle.Left && !(BoundingRectangle.Left > collidable.GetCollidableComponent().BoundingRectangle.Left) && IsCollidedWithObject(collidable, CollisionMode.BoundingRectangle);
    }
```

Okay, sorry if that's a massive unreadable amount of code, but I don't know of any better way to explain it.

Comment: Show us the code that pertains to your question.

Comment: Okay, I've added the collision detection code. If you need to see the resolution code, I'd be glad to post that, but I won't for the moment.

Comment: You described your problem just fine, so don't worry about that. The vague part is actually why you're doing the detection the way you described. I suggest you take a piece of paper and draw some bounding boxes in different intersecting positions coming at each other with different vectors and see if you can figure out the logic of correct collision detection and resolution. Then just write the correct steps in plain english (or your favorite human spoken/written language) to be able to correct any mistakes that you may make before translating those steps into the code.